# How to customize the terminal component in Primefaces 2.2.1 for JSF2?

Tags: java, css, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi guys I'd like to ask if there is a way to customize the terminal component in primefaces 2.2.1  ?  Id like to change the default prompt which is "prime $" into something else.  Also what are the other options for the "cursor" aside from "pointer".  Other customization tips regarding the terminal component will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *change the default prompt which is "prime $" into something else.*

Read the [User Guide](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) or use the IDE autocompletion to see all available component attributes. You need the `prompt` attribute. E.g.

```html
<p:terminal prompt="C:\\&gt;" ... />
```

This one will use `C:\>` instead of default `prime $`.

---

> *Also what are the other options for the "cursor" aside from "pointer".*

This actually belongs in a separate question as that's totally unrelated to JSF. But ala, just check the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#cursor-props). Here's an extract of relevance which shows all specified values:

> Value:    [ [<uri> ,]* [ auto | crosshair | default | pointer | move | e-resize | ne-resize | nw-resize | n-resize | se-resize | sw-resize | s-resize | w-resize | text | wait | help | progress ] ] | inherit