# Primefaces terminal customization

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm working with Primefaces 3.0.1.

I want to customize terminal component. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734735/how-to-customize-the-terminal-component-in-primefaces-2-2-1-for-jsf2), but I want to do one thing else, I don't know how(or even if it's possible).

I want to refresh prompt value on execution, using a value from a bean, but I don't know how to re-render it(or refresh it) without reloading the page.

I thank your help and patience in advance.